# Duplicates in dictionary keys. Merge dictionary values

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to find all the duplicates in the dictionary keys, take the values from the keys and save one key with all the values combined?

for example. Look at the data table below. If i wanted to save this as a dictionary with column "A" as key and column "B" as value:

[image: Data table]

Is it possible to remove the duplicates so that we only have ONE "A" key with the value = Thank;You;For;Helping"?

Comment: I don't think you can have duplicate keys in `Dictionary`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store a Collection (or Dictionary) object or an array as an item in the dictionary.

Something like:

***EDIT:** to printout the dictionary data*

```
Option Explicit
Sub marine()
    Dim D As Dictionary, C As Collection
    Dim V, W, I As Long, sKey As String
    
V = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
Set D = New Dictionary
    D.CompareMode = TextCompare
    
For I = 2 To UBound(V)
    sKey = V(I, 1)
    If Not D.Exists(sKey) Then
        Set C = New Collection
        C.Add V(I, 2)
        D.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=C
    Else
        D(sKey).Add V(I, 2)
    End If
Next I

For Each V In D.Keys
    For Each W In D(V)
        Debug.Print V, W
    Next W
Next V

End Sub
```

**debug.print output**

```
A             Thank
A             You
A             For
A             Helping
B             Car
C             Bus
D             Late
E             Damage
```

will give you a collection of all the items attached to each key.

[image]

[image]

---

As an aside, to concatenate all the values associated with a unique key, in Excel Office365 you can do this with formulas

Given your data:

```
E2: =UNIQUE($A$2:$A$9)
F2: =TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,FILTER($B$2:$B$9,($A$2:$A$9=E2)))
```

*Select `F2` and fill down as far as needed*

[image]

Comment: I get an error.

Dim D As Dictionary = Compile error: User-defined type not defined.

Comment: That's a different issue from what you asked about.  Do a search for the difference between early binding and late binding.  I used early binding, which means I set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  You can either set the reference yourself, or rewrite the declarations to use late-binding. `Dim D as Object; Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` or something like that.

Comment: I think the code is working. But i do not quite understand how to access this collection. For example, how to i debug.print it ?

Comment: @lass9509 Just treat `D("theKey")` as a `Collection`. You can iterate through using `For each..`, or, if you want the first element in `D("A")`, you would used `debug.print D("A")(1)`

Comment: @lass9509 See the revised code with debug.print output

Comment: Okay I see, thanks! So regarding this part of my question: Is it possible to remove the duplicates so that we only have ONE "A" key with the value = Thank;You;For;Helping"?

If i wanted to insert the values into a new column, so that "A" only appears once in column 1, but with "Thank;You;for;Helping" in column 2. is that possible?

Comment: @lass9509 I see you have changed your original question. That is considered bad form in this forum. If you have a new question you should be posting that as a new question - it is very hard to hit a moving target. But you can certainly just concatenate the contents of each dictionary item into your desired string.

Comment: Sorry. Let me redo the changes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: One last Question. Do you know how to append to a string in a loop. 
I = 1
x = 1
For Each V In D.keys
Ws.Cells(I, 4) = V
I = I + 1
For Each w In D(V)
finalString = ' MISSING
Ws.Cells(x, 5) = finalString
Next w
x = x + 1
Next V

I have created a string (finalString), but I dont know how to save all of the for each w in D(V)..

Comment: @lass9509 I suggest you post that as a new question.  Also, I will edit my Answer to provide a formula solution to your problem, if you have O365

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1.- Put this formula in the third column for every row to get true or false if your entry is not unique:

=COUNTIF(A:A;A2)>1
=COUNTIF(A:A;A3)>1
...and so on for each of the rows

2.- Then you have (verdadero = true and Falso = false)

[image]

3.- Then you can filter the true values in the 3rd column:

[image]

And build your string, but noy with A as a key, because keys cannot be duplicated in dictionaries. You need to use another data structure.

Al the steps taken are reproducible with code if you need to automate them, but faster user made.